# Swagger CodeGen Error- More than one inline schema specified in allOf:. Only the first one is recognized. All others are ignored

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I have a file provMnS.yaml and it is referring to some other file nrNrm.yaml where **SubNetwork-Single** model definition is present. **But due to allOf in the definition SubNetwork-Single model is not getting generated.** If I change allOf to oneOf then the model is generated. I have to use allOf only as per the specification yaml. Please help me to resolve it.

**Yaml snippet:**

```
  SubNetwork-Single:
          allOf:
            - $ref: 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Docs\Project\yyyy\tasks\2504\Latest16th-MnS-Rel-16-SA-91\MnS-Rel-16-SA-91\OpenAPI\genericNrm.yaml#/components/schemas/Top-Attr'
            - type: object
              properties:
                attributes:
                  allOf:
                    - $ref: 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Docs\Project\yyyy\tasks\2504\Latest16th-MnS-Rel-16-SA-91\MnS-Rel-16-SA-91\OpenAPI\genericNrm.yaml#/components/schemas/SubNetwork-Attr'
            - $ref: 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Docs\Project\yyyy\tasks\2504\Latest16th-MnS-Rel-16-SA-91\MnS-Rel-16-SA-91\OpenAPI\genericNrm.yaml#/components/schemas/SubNetwork-ncO'
            - type: object
              properties:
                SubNetwork:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/SubNetwork-Multiple'
```

**Error and Exception while running swagger-codegen-cli jar:**

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Docs\SWs\open api generator>java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.29.jar generate -i C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Docs/Project/yyyy/tasks/2504/Latest16th-MnS-Rel-16-SA-91/MnS-Rel-16-SA-91/OpenAPI/provMnS.yaml -l spring

23:18:22.457 [Thread-1] WARN  i.s.c.v.g.DefaultCodegenConfig - String to be sanitized is null. Default to Object
23:18:22.470 [Thread-1] WARN  i.s.c.v.g.DefaultCodegenConfig - More than one inline schema specified in allOf:. Only the first one is recognized. All others are ignored.
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process model 'SubNetwork-Single'.Please make sure that your schema is correct!
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generateModels(DefaultGenerator.java:386)
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:779)
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:388)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.DefaultCodegenConfig.addProperties(DefaultCodegenConfig.java:1527)
```

Comment: try Validate your shcema in yaml at https://editor.swagger.io/ and https://apitools.dev/swagger-parser/online/

Comment: It is valid I checked.. The problem is with swagger code generation as I am seeing that allOf is not allowing 2 $refs as elements but if I give one $ref it is working. Strange. I need to have both $ref so need help on this